# Can I create a dynamic framework from a Visual Studio C++ cross-platform library project?

Tags: c++, ios, visual-studio-2017, cross-platform

I created a Shared Library (Android, iOS) project in VS2017. The android project builds well and output a libXXX.so file. But for iOS, the result is a libXXX.iOS.a, which is a iOS static library. Can it generate a dynamic framework instead of a static library (.a)? How to do that?

I don't want a static library because it is legacy and too large. The android libXXX.so is 8KB but iOS static library libXXX.iOS.a is 986KB!

result of iOS build:

```
1>libEzp.iOS.vcxproj -> host: 10.10.x.x  output: /Users/z/vcremote/D/workspace/x/libXXX/ARM/Debug//libXXX.iOS.a
```

project type:

[image: project type]

project property: only static library .a is available
[image: only static library (.a) is available]

Environment: VS2017 15.9.3 Community

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dynamic Libraries (.dylib) aren't directly supported on iOS. You will have to bundle them in a framework (which is something Visual Studio doesn't currently support).